# scroll event in nuxt.js with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to change color of my appbar on scroll. How can i achieve that with Vuetify?
I already tried something like this from Vuetify docs

```
  <div>
    <v-row
      justify="center"
      align="center"
    >
      <v-subheader>Offset Top</v-subheader>
      {{ offsetTop }}
    </v-row>
    <v-container
      id="scroll-target"
      style="max-height: 400px"
      class="overflow-y-auto"
    >
      <v-row
        v-scroll:#scroll-target="onScroll"
        align="center"
        justify="center"
        style="height: 1000px"
      >
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </div>
```

But i don't understand how it works and my appbar didn't change color.